# error: call of overloaded is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading

```
bool find_solutions(const string if_need_all, vector< vector<char> > table, vector<int> ships, int row[], int col[]){
  sort(ships.begin(), ships.end(), greater<int>());//sort the ship length in descending order
  static int counter = 0; //counter that tracks if the ship is to be placed vertically or horizontally
  static int s = 0; //index of ship using
  int fill;//ship to fill
  int filling;//keep track how much the ship has been filled 
  if(s == ships.size()) return true;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<table.size(); ++i){
    filling = 0;
    fill = ships[s];
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j<table[i].size(); ++j){
      if(counter == 0 && insertable(table,row,col,i,j,counter,fill)){
        while(filling<fill){
          table[i][j+filling] = fill;
          col[j+filling]--;
          filling++;
        }
        row[i] -= fill; s++;
        find_solutions(if_need_all, table, ships, row,col);
      } 
      else{
        counter++;
      }
      if(counter == 1 && insertable(table,row,col,i,j,counter,fill)){
        while(filling<fill){
          table[i+filling][j] = fill;  
          row[i+filling]--;
          filling++;
        }
        col[j] -= fill; s++;
        find_solutions(if_need_all, table, ships, row, col);
      }
      else{
        counter--;
      }
    }
  }
  if(s != ships.size()) return false;
  else return true;
}
main.cpp: In function ‘bool find_solutions(std::__cxx11::string,     std::vector<std::vector<char> >, std::vector<int>, int*, int*)’:
main.cpp:277:67: error: call of overloaded     ‘insertable(std::vector<std::vector<char> >&, int*&, int*&, unsigned int&,    unsigned int&, int&, int&)’ is ambiguous
       if(counter == 0 && insertable(table,row,col,i,j,counter,fill)){
                                                               ^
main.cpp:13:6: note: candidate: bool insertable(const     std::vector<std::vector<char> >&, const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)
 bool insertable(const vector< vector<char> >& inboard, const int r[], const int c[],
      ^
main.cpp:125:6: note: candidate: bool insertable(std::vector<std::vector<char> >, const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)
 bool insertable(const vector< vector<char> > inboard,const int r[], const int c[],co
      ^
```

can anyone tell me what mistake i've made?
I searched online that websites says it's either variable created several times or function name already exists in STL library. I checked both conditions and they do not apply to my problem. Is it the fill causing problem or other variable, or it's the function ?

Comment: where is your "insertable" function?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to provide a meaningful answer, but it looks like you are `using namespace std`. There is plenty of room for nastiness such as a function you define getting in a scrap with an identically named function in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You have overloaded `insertable()` with the below parameter types.

```
bool insertable(const std::vector<std::vector<char> >&,
                const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)

bool insertable(std::vector<std::vector<char> >,
                const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)
```

Let us assume `T` as

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<char> > T;
```

The first parameter in both method definition is ambiguous because both methods can accept types `T` and `T&` as first parameter, So the compiler can't decide which overloaded method to invoke. BTW you should not create overloaded methods which differs in `reference` instead you should use an entirely different type. Because a type and its reference are always compatible hence considered as same.

For ex. `int` and `int&`  are compatible, so `insertable(int a)` and `insertable(int& b)`  are same. If you call this method like below the compiler can't decide which method to call.

```
int x = 20;
insertable(x);
```

In the same way, below definitions are also same if you used non const `T` in function call.

```
bool insertable(const T&, const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)

bool insertable(T, const int*, const int*, int, int, int, int)
```

[@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) in comments:

`T` and `const T&` are always ambiguous. However `T` and `T&` are not ambiguous when the argument is an *rvalue*. The *rvalue* cannot bind to `T&`, and it is a valid use case to overload separately for *rvalues* than *lvalues*

Comment: `T` and `const T&` are always ambiguous. However `T` and `T&` are not ambiguous when the argument is an rvalue.   The rvalue cannot bind to `T&`.